# Two identical functions one works one does not

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I created two functions, **GOODself** and **BADself**, called in succession to debug a problem I have in a larger script [illustrated here](http://dna.cfsna.net/HAP/Modified-yUtility.htm). I can't figure out why **BADself** stalls at the line **`aryVarAbi[0] = 5;`**.

If I call it first it still happens. According to the console in Firefox **`aryVarAbi`** is not defined.

```
GAB = GOODself(0, 4, 1);
GAB = BADself(0, 4, 1);

function GOODself(GABin, nCols, nRows) {
    var aCol = 0;
    var aryVarABi = [1,1,1,1];
    for (aCol=0; aCol < nCols - 1; aCol++) {
        alert("GOOD1 " + aryVarABi[aCol]);
        aryVarABi[0]= 5;
        alert("GOOD2 " + aryVarABi[aCol]);
    } // for aCol
    return (aryVarABi[0]);
} // GOODself

function BADself(GABin, nCols, nRows) {
    var aCol = 0;
    var aryVarABi = [1,1,1,1];
    for (aCol=0; aCol < nCols - 1; aCol++) {
        alert("BAD1 " + aryVarABi[aCol]);
        aryVarAbi[0] = 5;
        alert("BAD2 " + aryVarABi[aCol]);
    } // for aCol
    return (aryVarABi[0]);
} // BADself
```

Comment: You have to be careful about capitalization. `aryVarABi` looks to be defined, but `aryVarAbi` is not.

Comment: What do you mean by "stalls" do you get an error message. Try a debugger.

Comment: the debugger should point you at the problem. Look at `aryVarAbi` in your bad function, right after the first alert. That is not `aryVarABi`. Please use concise names for your variables because that kind of naming can lead to problems ... like you got.

Comment: Hi Colin, this is very easy to spot if you use something like Developer Tools in the Goole Chrome browser. When you paste the above code into the console it gives the answer and even the line number, see:Uncaught ReferenceError: aryVarAbi is not defined
    at BADself (<anonymous>:20:5)

Comment: Why do you have two copies of the same function? You should just write the function once then call it wherever you need to. Then you avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case senstive.  You've defined `var aryVarABi = [1,1,1,1];`. Notice the capital B.  You're referring to `aryVarAbi[0] = 5;`.  Notice the lowercase b.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `aryVarABi[0] = 5;` as opposed to `aryVarAbi[0] = 5;`

The 'b' in the latter is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variables are case sensitive, so *aryVarABi* is a different variable from *aryVarAbi*.

Please change the line `aryVarAbi[0] = 5;` to `aryVarABi[0] = 5;`.